# How to change color of a specific list

Tags: html, css

I wanna be able to change colors of only the items of the list that has a number in it to blue.

I basically only want to change the list the color of my first list ( the ol li ) meaning the list that start with a number in it.

```css
ol li {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>League 1<br>
    <ul type="circle">
      <li>Buts</li>
      <li>Buts top
        <ul type="a">
          <li>...</li>
          <li></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Stats</li>
    </ul>

  </li>
  <li>League 2</li>
  <li>Coupe</li>
</ol>
```

I tried this but it didnt work, all the lists changed color to blue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **DO NOT POST IMAGES OF CODE**. Please paste your code directly into the question. Use the `<>` stack snippet tool to add your HTML and CSS. Also, CSS cannot do this. It is content unaware - meaning it cannot read your text and change the color based on the text.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text

Comment: thank you sir i edited my post. im not sure this is the answer im looking for because what I meant is that in my code there are multiple types of lists there are ol li, then ul li, then ul "type a"li, im not able to change the color of just the first type ?

Comment: If that's the case, update your post with your HTML as well, and tell use exactly what you want changed - in your question, not the comments.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `initial` to reset the color on the nested lists.

Why do we need to use `initial`? Because color is inherited in descendant elements.

```css
/*Target just the list items that are children of ol*/
ol>li {
  color: blue;
}


/*Target list items in an ul that is a decendant of ol */
ol ul>li {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>League 1<br>
    <ul type="circle">
      <li>Buts</li>
      <li>Buts top
        <ul type="a">
          <li>...</li>
          <li></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Stats</li>
    </ul>

  </li>
  <li>League 2</li>
  <li>Coupe</li>
</ol>
```

On a side note it is important to know the difference between the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) and the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
 ol li span {
   color: blue;
 }
</style>

<ol>
    <li><span>Something</span><li>
</ol>
```